# Add TableView scroll gesture to View

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, scrollview, gesture

Basically I have a UITableView with a UIView in each row. The problem is this UIView is stealing the scrolling gesture from the UITableView resulting in a TableView which doesn't scroll. How do I apply the scroll gesture from the UITableView to the UIView?

Comment: How are you adding the UIView into the table view? post some code

Comment: I'm adding the UIView as a subview of the cell.contentView

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you didn't do this already, Add a customTableViewCell class into your project and create an xib along with it (add the UIView subclass you created into the xib and as a property of the custom cell class). 
After that add this code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects;
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomTableViewCell class]])
            cell = (CustomTableViewCell *) currentObject;
    }
}
cell.yourView = ...;
```

Hope this helps